# Get User ID in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to obtain the User ID (instead of email address) in Google Apps Script using the [Session service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session) or similar.

I haven't seen any reference to it in GAS, but within GAE I am able to obtain the User ID from the [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/). The User ID is an identifier that uniquely identifies a user, even if the user changes their email address.

I am hoping to use the same in GAS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Is it possible to obtain the User ID (instead of email address) in Google Apps Script using the Session service or similar?***

Yes, it's possible. You can obtain User IDs by leveraging the [AdminSDK Directory API which is accessible from App Script via the Admin Directory Advanced Google Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory).

Sample Usage:

```
// NOTE: Admin Directory Advanced Service must be enabled first.

// Get first page of user ids for users in domain
var userIds = AdminDirectory.Users.list({"domain":"www.example.com"}).users.map(function(user) { 
    return user.id; 
});
```

Comment: Op doesn't mention if they are or are not in a GSuite environment - Admin Directory is only available there. Can you comment on the difference between the Drive `permissionId` and the Admin Directory `userId`? (I have no access to Admin Directory to test it.)

Comment: @tehhowch The python User API the OP references in the topic post is simply a wrapper for the AdminSDK so its safe to assume that he/she is using a GSuite account. As the OP stated, the `userId` uniquely identifies a user even if they change properties of their account. The `permissionId` may be the same thing (I'd have to check). However, the `userId` is also available from the Google+ API which you can reference without a GSuite account.

Comment: lots of ways to skin Google's cats :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the "advanced service" Drive REST API to query the [`About` resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource), which can return a more nuanced `user` object:

```
function getInfo() {
  var about = Drive.About.get();
  // Use the name, permissionId, email, etc
  var user = {
    name: about.name,
    permissionId: about.permissionId,
    driveUser: about.user,
    ....
  };

  return user;
}
```

Or the [`Drive.Permissions.getIdForEmail`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/getIdForEmail) method if that is all you want.

If the automatic scope detection is too aggressive, you may try adding one of the `.readonly` scopes to your manifest instead: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get#auth

Note: you will have to [enable the advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) client library, and its underlying API, before it can be used in your Apps Script project.

See also:

- [Drive "Advanced Service"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)
- [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk)